# QT-OpenCV on Beaglebone Black

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use OpenCV and QT on Beaglebone Black by using this tutorial : [https://aplacetogeek.wordpress.com/qt-opencv-v4l-cross-compiling-raspberry-pi-beagle-bone/](http://link)

I've completed first 6 step with Ubuntu 14.04 as a host computer operating system, and latest angstrom image as target machine operating system. And i have 4DCape-43T touch screen to test the GUI program.

I wrote a basic qt "hello world" console application. It seems console application works fine, because I can see the "hello world" output. But when I try to run a basic GUI application with "-qws" command, it seems work fine on console output but there is no QT window or running GUI program.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: the point was, i wasn't getting any error message. I just couldn't see the windows or anything displayed. But i figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, i just couldn't use gdm service and qt-application at the same time. To see the output, i needed to disable gdm service, - by using "systemctl disable gdm.service" command- and it works ok now.

For more information and help about qt on embedded, you should check out Derek Molloy's tutorials. I found this problem on his 2nd. video.

http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/qt-with-embedded-linux-on-the-beaglebone/